# Trying to get only first page results of amazon search

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm currently trying to have this query only return the first page of the results.  I'm currently using [python amazon api](https://bitbucket.org/basti/python-amazon-product-api) and this is my code.

```
#!python

api = API(cfg=config.amzconfig)

query='justin bieber'
thingy = api.item_search('Blended', ResponseGroup='Large', Keywords=query)
print(thingy)
for thing in thingy:
    # print(lxml.etree.tostring(item, pretty_print=True))
    try:
        print('%s' % thing.ItemAttributes.Title)
        print('%s' % thing.DetailPageURL)
        print('%s' % thing.SmallImage.URL)
    except:
        continue
```

This works fine, but returns a really large amount of results.  On the other hand if I do as it says in their documentation and add in `paginate=False` it returns no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through the source, you can put a `limit=1` to get the number of pages